# visitors - dynamic change of traverse type which depends on node

Tags: algorithm, compiler-construction, code-generation, visitor-pattern

Let's consider such syntax: "case when a > 1 then 1 else 0". I have to generate byte code for such expression. I have AST which looks like:

```
       -----------------------case----------------
       |                       |                 |
       |                       |                 |
    whenthen-----           whenthen            else
       |        |              |                 |
       |        |              |                 |
      when    then           .....      Numerical expression
       |        |
       |Numerical expression
Boolean expression
```

As soon as I start writes on paper byte code for such expression, it' starts to be clear that code generation differs for arithmetical expressions and label and jump code generation. Traverse type for numerical or boolean expression is different than for case when syntax so I need to switch between traverse algorithm depends on currently visited node.

It really confusing me, how to implement visitor pattern that can change traverse type dynamically and do not move traversing to accept() methods. I would like to keep traverse algorithm decoupled from nodes. How such problem should be solved properly, how compiler-makers solve it. Is there anything I could use to make this problem easier to solve?

Comment: The confusing thing about the visitor pattern when visiting an AST is that the visitor can't follow the tree's recursivity, it has to be more procedural. However, it's possible, normally you have a stack register to store each operation for your node algorithm in bytecode. Anyways, would be nice having a look on what you've implemented of your visitor, also, would be nice having an idea of your bytecode operations.